Confidence int. expands much more rapidly than prediction int. as we depart from $\bar X$
In this post we see a regression plot (pasted below) with a confidence interval (CI) and a prediction interval (PI). The CI is expanding fairly noticeably as we get further away from the mean of $X$ (here, wt) while the PI barely expands at all. Why is that?

I can recreate similar behavior with another example:

m1 <- lm(wt~qsec, data=mtcars)
mpi <- cbind(mtcars, 
             predict(m1, interval="confidence", level=0.90), 
             predict(m1, interval="prediction", level=0.90))
mpi <- mpi[,-(ncol(mpi)-2)]
ggplot(mpi, aes(x=qsec)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=wt)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit), color="blue", size=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=lwr.1), color="red", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(y=upr.1), color="red", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), fill="red", alpha=0.10)


The formulas would be on page 39 in Faraday's Practical Regression and Anova using R (2002). Are you looking for an answer that takes them as given and chases through the consequences of "the predition $x_0$ being far away from the modeling $X$" in the formulas, or for something more conceptual?

@StephanKolassa, I am not exactly sure. I do not get the intuition of this behavior. I would expect the additional uncertainty from going from CI to PI to be the same regardless of where we are. Hmm, but might this actually hold for variances instead of standard deviations? And since the CI and PI are based on the latter, we get the "distortion"? This would be intuitive enough. And if so, now I probably could answer my own question...

@RichardHardy: I guess the reason is that the prediction interval is dominated by the extra variance term from the future observation, and that should not depend on the distance from the mean ...

... under the crucial assumption of homoskedasticity.

Standard errors/standard deviations don't 'add'.

Perhaps it's an optical illusion, but the red lines in the second example seem to be bending, and the black lines in the first example might be bending, too.

@Dave, sure, PI are bending. My wording was imprecise, so it may have implied I thought they were constant. I did not mean that. My question is why they are bending much slower than the CI. I have edited the post to clarify.

This is a direct consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem ;-).

Just so. Note that if we have two components $s$ and $l$ with $r=s/l<<1$ then $\sqrt{l^2+s^2}$ $\approx$ $l(1+r^2/2)$. That is, if the smaller component is some modest fraction $r$ of the larger, it shifts the standard error of prediction very little in percentage terms. This specific line of thought was what I had in mind with "standard errors don't add" ... and indeed it is just Pythagoras. e.g if $s=0.2 l$ then $\sqrt{l^2+s^2}\approx 1.02 l$. (!) .. this is all the intuition needed, IMO

Remember that the width of the intervals is based on the estimate of the standard deviation of what we are predicting.  For the confidence interval that is just the standard error of the predicted mean.  For the prediction interval it is based on both the standard error of the predicted mean and the estimate of the standard deviation of the residuals.
But the important part for understanding your question is that the combination is on the variance scale, not the standard deviation scale.
So for example we can consider a case where the standard error of the predicted mean is $1$ at $\bar{x}$, and is $2$ at a value away from $\bar{x}$, and the estimated standard deviation of the residuals is $5$.
The width of the confidence interval at $\bar{x}$ will be proportional to $1$ and proportional to $2$ at our other point.  So the width of the confidence interval will be twice as wide at our comparison point.
The widths of the prediction intervals will be proportional to:
> sqrt(1^2 + 5^2)
[1] 5.09902

and
> sqrt(2^2 + 5^2)
[1] 5.385165

with a ratio of
> 5.385165/5.09902
[1] 1.056118

So where the confidence interval is twice as wide, the prediction interval will be about 6% wider.
Go ahead an try this with other values of the standard error and estimated standard deviation to see how they compare.
Hope this helps,

Thanks! It does help.

" based on both the standard error of the predicted mean and the estimate of the standard deviation of the residuals" $${}$$ Actually I think you must have meant "an estimate of the standard deviation of the errors." The residuals are observable estimates of the unobservable errors. The errors are independent; the residuals are not, since they must satisfy two linear constraints: that their sum is $0$ and that the sum of their products with the corresponding $x$ values is $0.$ The errors, as opposed to the residuals, will not satisfy those constraints.

@MichaelHardy, Yes, we agree on concept.  But not all sources make the same distinction that you do and in some cases the 2 terms are used interchangeably, terms like "theoretical" ,"true", or "observed" added when it is important to make the distinction.  After all, the Sum of Squares Error is calculated from the observed deviations, not the true but unknown ones.

ok . . . . . I hate using the word "true" in this way. One may speak of a sample mean and of a population mean, and the latter is the one people call the "true" mean, but the term "population mean" makes clear what it is without implying that the sample mean is a "false" mean.

@MichaelHardy, I agree, terms like "population" and "theoretical" are better terms than "true".

I think the reason is that the prediction intervals are dominated by the variance term from the future observation, at least as long we are not too far from the mean. The formulas from the link in comments becomes, for the case of simple linear regression (with homoskedasticity) and with centered predictors, such that $\bar{x}=0$:
\begin{equation}
\hat{y}_0 \pm t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{1+\frac1n +\frac{x_0^2}{x^Tx}}   \\
\hat{y}_0 \pm t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{\frac1n +\frac{x_0^2}{x^Tx}} 
\end{equation}
For prediction at the mean, $x_0=0$. To simplify further, assume $n$ is large enough that we can use asymptotic approximations, then $x^Tx$ will be approximately $(n-1)\sigma^2$ and $\hat{\sigma}\approx \sigma$, so the half-width terms becomes
\begin{equation}
t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \sigma \sqrt{1+\frac1n +\frac{x_0^2}{(n-1)\sigma^2}} \\
t_{n-p}^{\alpha/2} \sigma \sqrt{\frac1n +\frac{x_0^2}{(n-1)\sigma^2}}
\end{equation}
Out to a distance from the mean where $x_0\approx \sqrt{(n-1)\sigma^2}$, which in many cases should include the range of interest, the term under the root sign for the prediction interval varies from 1 to 2, while for the confidence interval it varies from $\frac1n$ to  1, roughly.
(If there is doubt about the approximations, note that a change from the asymptotic values have the same effect on both curves, so does affect the comparison too much)

+1 That was helpful, thank you! Both answers were helpful but I can accept only one of them, so forgive me for putting the check mark next to the other one.
